# Keyframe is not working with an AngularJS dynamically added class in Firefox or Safari

Tags: angularjs, css, cross-browser, css-animations

I'm trying to add a class dynamically to an element in my dom when the model it is associated with in angular is true, but in Firefox and Safari (works fine with Chrome), the keyframe associated with the class (spinning) are not showing up.

Html:

```
<span class="{{loading ? 'loader' : ''}}"><i class="fa fa-github fa-4x"></i></span>
```

Css:

```
.loader {
    text-align: center;
    margin: 20px;
    height: 40px;
    -webkit-animation-name: spin;
    -webkit-animation-duration: 1000ms;
    -webkit-animation-iteration-count: infinite;
    -webkit-animation-timing-function: linear;
    -moz-animation-name: spin;
    -moz-animation-duration: 1000ms;
    -moz-animation-iteration-count: infinite;
    -moz-animation-timing-function: linear;
    -ms-animation-name: spin;
    -ms-animation-duration: 1000ms;
    -ms-animation-iteration-count: infinite;
    -ms-animation-timing-function: linear;

    animation-name: spin;
    animation-duration: 1000ms;
    animation-iteration-count: infinite;
    animation-timing-function: linear;
}
@-ms-keyframes spin {
    from { -ms-transform: rotate(0deg); }
    to { -ms-transform: rotate(360deg); }
}
@-moz-keyframes spin {
    from { -moz-transform: rotate(0deg); }
    to { -moz-transform: rotate(360deg); }
}
@-webkit-keyframes spin {
    from { -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg); }
    to { -webkit-transform: rotate(360deg); }
}
@keyframes spin {
    from {
        transform:rotate(0deg);
    }
    to {
        transform:rotate(360deg);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not the good way to add class depending of a variable:

```
<span ng-class="{ 'loader' : loading }"><i class="fa fa-github fa-4x"></i></span>
```

And the problem is the styles, you need use

```
display:block
```

because Safari expects a block for apply this property.

You have an example here:
http://codepen.io/luarmr/pen/VLPBqJ

Comment: the first was a suggestion, the second is the real problem.